# the process cannot access the file, it is still being used error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are a lot of answers on this question on stackoverflow itself. But I didn't understand what was actually happening.

I tried to upload a file, where file may be in count also.

**Below is my part of code creating problem-**

```
 public ActionResult Upload(List<HttpPostedFileBase> file, CardModel card) {
            foreach (var item in file) {
                CardTable cardtable = new CardTable();
               if (item != null && item.ContentLength > 0) {
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
                    if (ImageExtension(extension)) {
                        string path = Server.MapPath("~/CardPhotos/");
                        item.SaveAs(path + item.FileName);
                        string filename = item.FileName;
```

While saving a file `item.SaveAs(path+item.FileName);` shows me this error "The process cannot access the file, It is being used by another process.

An alternate solution was about using `Sleep` but first I want to understand this exception and want to know what is an obvious solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can Dispose the file after saving/creating, something like this.

```
item.SaveAs(path + item.FileName);
item.Dispose();
```

Alternatively, you can put the save in a using block, similar to below.

```
using(var i = new HttpPostedFileBase(item))
{
    i.Save(path + item.FileName);
}
```

Another reason that I could think of, is that the new upload file is trying to overwrite the existing file, and the existing file was opened on the server.